# Non-homogeneous Solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Could you please check this solution?

I am given:

$y''-4y'-5y=2e^{2t}$

The particular solution should take the form:

$y=Ae^{2t}$

Then we have:

$y'=2Ae^{2t}$

$y''=4Ae^{2t}$

Solving for A gives: $A=-2/17$

So: $y_p=(-2/17)e^{2t}$

Does that look right?

Comment: You didn't calculate $A$ right. It should be something similar, but not $-2/17$. Try again. And when you find one particular solution of non-homogeneous equation, than you only need to find solution of homogeneous equation.

Comment: I got $A=\frac{-2}{9}$, check the signs because I ended up with $4-8-5=-9$ and you might have $-4-8-5=-17$

Comment: Yup.  You're right.  This is what happens when I rely on my terrible arithmetic!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write the ODE as follows also:

$$y''-4y'-5y=2e^{2t}\longrightarrow(D^2-4D-5)y=2e^{2t}\color{red}{\equiv}(D-5)(D+1)y=2e^{2t}$$ Since the associated homogenous ODE has the general solution as $$y_c(t)=C_1e^{-t}+C_2e^{5t}$$ so, you can assume that $y_p(t)=Ae^{2t}$. I agree with Francisco in finding that constant $A$.

Comment: Despite majoring in math, I am terrible at arithmetic.  Thanks for your help!  Just curious, but the general solution y(t) is $y_c + y_p$ right?  That would make $y(t)=C_1e^-t+C_2e^(5t)+(-2/9)e^(2t)$ ?

Comment: @westhe32nd: Yes! that is right. :-)